# How to get changes in the object properties inside the array with vue $watch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to get object properties change inside the array.
For to do that, I'm using vue.$watch.
I read the documentation but I didn't get that.

The scenario is:

```
...
data() {
        return {            
            Questions: [{foo: 1}, {foo: 2}, {foo: 3}]
        }
    },
...

this.$watch("Questions", function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // something...
}, { deep: true });
```

**UPDATED**

The solution is here!

[See the example on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonatan2m/h7sm7wbr/)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what it is not working with your jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Javascript limitation - if you change array elements directly (e.g. `this.array[0].foo = 'bar'`), Vue cannot track these changes, hence the watcher will not be triggered.

It will be triggered though if you use any of `Array.prototype` functions, like `push`, `pop` or will re-assign array.

So the most basic solution will look this way:

```
change: function () {
  let questions = this.Questions;
  questions[0].foo = 5;

  this.Questions = questions;
  
  /* or
   let index = 0;
   let question = this.Questions[index];
   question.foo = 5;
   this.Questions.splice(index, 1, question);
  */
}
```

---

Updated jsFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h7sm7wbr/3/)

Stuff to check out: [Arrays reactivity in Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

Comment: Thanks @yev. Although the example makes the change on **change** method, I need that code works with two-way binding, though. I've just found a workaround and I'll update the example. But, even so I'll give you a upvote! :)